# aimer/aimer à/aimer de

Tags: usage, constructions, de, évolution, à

> **J'aimerais de lire** toute la journée. — [(Eugénie de Guérin, Journal, 10
>   décembre 1834)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aimer_de)
>
> Wagner n'échappe pas à la règle: **il aimait à séduire**, se rassurant
>   ainsi sur son désir de plaire, rançon d'une frustration de tendresse à
>   la recherche de l'amante-mère qu'incarnera sa seconde femme, Cosima
>   Liszt. — [(Sylvie Oussenko & ‎François Poncet, Wagner: vie et œuvre,
>   Éditions Eyrolles, 2013, page 22)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aimer_%C3%A0)

Je n'ai pas appris qu'aimer peut être suivi par *à* ou *de*. Littré en parle aussi. Pourquoi ces constructions ne sont pas connues ? Sont-elles archaïques ? Est-ce l'usage qui les a rendu archaïques ?  Est-ce l'Académie française ?

Comment: L'usage seul décide du sort d'une langue vivante, donc du caractère archaïque d'une tournure ou pas. Ce n'est pas l'Académie qui en décide, au plus peut-elle l'encourager ou recommander de l'éviter, mais sans garantie de succès.

Comment: @jlliagre Ton commentaire et la réponse reçue répondent à ma question. Merci.

Comment: L'usage du *de* comme ça me donne vraiment l'impression que c'est ... du vieux français, c'est une construction que je ne pense jamais utiliser, que ce soit à l'oral comme à l'écrit :O

Comment: @damadam Merci pour le commentaire. N'étant pas natif, j'ai du mal à distinguer entre vieux français et contemporain français:-)!

Comment: @dimitris français contemporain*

Comment: @damadam Oups! Merci. Mais je pensais que contemporain fait partie des adjectifs qui peuvent précéder ou suivre un nom sans souci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La première l'est (archaïque); la seconde est littéraire: on peut l'utiliser dans du langage formel de narration.