# Ne pas aimer (un) autre homme / d'autre homme

Tags: articles, négation, littérature

Bonjour,

Dans [*L'enfant*](http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/%7Ewulfric/frebase/maupas_6/enfant.htm) de Maupassant :

> Je n'ai pas **aimé d**'autre homme que toi... Promets-moi de ne pas
> l'abandonner.

Je ne comprends pas très bien l'usage de la preposition *de* ici.

Y a-t-il une différence entre ne pas aimer *(un) autre homme* et ne pas aimer *d'autre homme* ?

Comment: Ovide, quand c'est clair dans le dico et dans la phrase, alors, c'est bien ça, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: Pardonnez-moi, mais le doute est sincère. À votre avis, la tournure est plutôt littéraire ici ? Je n'avais jamais vu ça

Comment: Ok, j'ai régardé la page, et j'ai fait plusieurs recherches et je ne trouve pas la phrase....:)

Comment: La phrase de Maupassant ? http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/~wulfric/frebase/maupas_6/enfant.htm

Comment: Tu fais une confusion : c'est aimer de + infinitif qui est signalé comme littéraire dans le TLF (et j'ajouterais vieillie). Dans la phrase que tu cites il s'agit de l'emploi normal de aimer suivi d'un groupe nominal  complément. Et la différence est entre **un** autre homme et **d'** autre homme, aucune des deux n'est plus littéraire que l'autre.

Comment: Non, Ovide, le verbe aimer suivi de la particule (je n'ai pas trouvé dans le TLF). Il me semble (et il est très possible que je me trompe), que aimer d'autre homme est plus **prononçable** que: aimer un autre homme. Les francophones n'aiment pas trop les sonorités: [verbe]er un autre.

Comment: @None Merci beaucoup !

Comment: @Lambie C'est la négation qui entraine l'emploi de **de**.

Comment: On ne peut pas dire: "Je n'ai pas aimé un autre homme."?

Comment: @Lambie si, c'est possible, nuances. Je suis quasi sûre qu'il y a déjà des questions à ce sujet sur FL, mais pas encore trouvé, je cherche...

Comment: @None https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31336/aimer-aimer-%c3%a0-aimer-de Il vaut mieux, alors, effacer cette question ?

Comment: Oui, mais ça ne correspond pas à ton cas. Tu peux aussi la reformuler et demander pourquoi **un** et pas **de** (ce qui est ton cas dans ta question). J'ai trouvé cette réponse https://french.stackexchange.com/a/44785/358, si c'est assez pour toi, tu effaces si tu veux !

Comment: @None Mille mercis !

Comment: Si on dit en français, "Je mange des bananes tous les jours". Je ne vois pas comment le négatif "entraine" le de. Le "de" y est déjà:  Je ne mange pas des bananes tous les jours.

Comment: @Lambie  Dans le cas que tu donnes la phrase a un **article défini** : *les*, et à la forme négative (sauf nuance spéciale) l'article défini disparait (donc reste *de*). *Je ne mange pas des bananes tous les jours* et *je ne mange pas de bananes tous les jours* représentent des contextes (et des nuances donc) différents. Dans le cas de la question d'Ovide c'est *un* qui disparait et *de* qui apparait. La règle générale est : Les articles indéfinis  et partitifs  deviennent **de** quand il y a une négation dans la phrase.  Mais les articles peuvent rester quand on veut introduire une nuance.

Comment: @None Merci ! C'est plus clair pour moi maintenant. Je pense qu'il y une bonne réponse dans ton commentaire.

Comment: @None Je comprends la différence entre des bananes et de bananes. Je ne pense pas qu'on puisse dire que le "un" disparait et le "de" apparait. S'il n'a jamais eu un "un".

Comment: Je mange les bananes et je manges des bananes. Le les n'est pas "présent".

Comment: @None  _Dans le cas que tu donnes la phrase a un article défini : les, et à la forme négative (sauf nuance spéciale) **l'article défini disparait** (donc reste de)._ --- Désolée, je ne comprends pas cette phrase. _Je mange **des** bananes tous **les** jours_ "des" est un article indéfini. _Je ne mange pas **de** bananes tous **les** jours._ Quel article **défini** disparait ici ?

Comment: @None Merci. _ Dans : Je mange des bananes : il y a l'article partitif des des = de les._ --- C'est intéressant ! Je ne l'aurais jamais pensé... Je n'ai vu cette explication nulle part.

Comment: @Oreste On s'attend à ce que le partitif soit  *je mange de la banane* mais on préfère dire *je mange des bananes* comme on dit *je mange des frites*. C'est bien un partitif car on parle dans les deux cas d'une quantité indéfinie, qu'on ne dénombre pas. Si on compte les bananes, la négation sera de toute façon *de* aussi.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est ce que je pensais moi aussi. Je ne pense pas que l'article défini soit caché là.

Comment: @Oreste Si, l'article défini est bien caché dans ce *des*.  La phrase "Je mange **des** bananes" (c'est à dire "de **les** bananes") a la même structure que "je bois de **l** 'eau" qui contient bien un article défini ("de **la** eau").

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne comprends pas, pourquoi écrire "je mange de **les** bananes" ? Quelque chose m'échappe...

Comment: @Oreste Non, justement, on n'écrit pas *de les bananes*, le partitif et le défini fusionnent, comme dans *je mange **des** frites*. TLFi "[de/des, article partitif](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/des/1)" *b) [Si le nom au pluriel, quoique désignant des choses nombrables, désigne, en vertu de son usage, une catégorie] Manger des œufs. Ils avaient plaisir à nommer tout haut les légumes : Tiens, des carottes! Ah! des choux! (Flaubert, Bouvard,t. 1, 1880, p. 20).*

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, je voulais dire pourquoi vouloir cacher l'article défini dans l'article partitif, je ne comprends pas cette logique, mais ce n'est pas grave.

Comment: @Oreste **De les** devient **des**  de la même manière que **de le** devient **du**. C'est pour ça qu'on dit qu'un article défini est "caché" dedans.

Answer (score 2):

Dans une phrase dont le verbe est à la forme négative la règle générale est de mettre *de* à la place de l'article indéfini devant le COD de ce verbe.

> Lorsqu’ils se trouvent dans une phrase négative avec ne… pas, ne… plus, etc., l’article indéfini (un, une, des) et l’article partitif (du, de la, des) sont habituellement réduits à de (ou d’) devant le complément direct. ([BDL](https://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3514))

Donc *de* (**article indéfini** ici et **non pas** préposition) est la forme tout à fait normale qui doit être dans la phrase :

> Je n'ai pas aimé d'autre homme que toi... Promets-moi de ne pas l'abandonner.

*De* ne peut pas être employé dans la forme affirmative de cette phrase puisque le COD est singulier. On ne dit pas :

- <strike>J'ai aimé d'autre homme que toi.</strike>

mais

- J'ai aimé un autre homme que toi.

Et ceci n'a absolument aucun rapport avec le fait que l'adjectif employé soit le mot *autre*. On dit : « J'ai écrit une lettre./ Je n'ai pas écrit de lettre. »

Mettre *de* à la place de l'article indéfini est la règle générale, ce qui veut dire qu'**il est possible**, et correct, de dire :  « Je n'ai pas aimé un autre homme que toi. »

> Y a-t-il une différence entre *ne pas aimer un autre homme* et *ne pas aimer d'autre homme ?*

On peut voir une nuance selon les contextes. Dans le cas de la phrase de Maupassant,  s'il y en a une, elle me parait ténue et toute interprétation sujette à discussion. En poussant assez loin je dirais qu'on pourrait éventuellement considérer que  « Je n'ai pas aimé un autre homme que toi » rendrait les sentiments de la *fille Ravet* vis à vis de Bourdillère plus vagues, moins consistants, et que « d'autre homme que toi » garde à cet amour sa forme exclusive : Bourdillère à été le seul et unique amour de sa vie.

Dans une tout autre situation, par exemple : « Je n'ai pas aimé un autre homme que toi, j'ai aimé une femme » il me semblerait indispensable de mettre *un* car on aurait là deux éléments en contraste.

Si on ne peut pas écrire  <strike>J'ai aimé d'autre homme que toi</strike> on peut, et on doit, écrire  « J'ai aimé d'autres hommes que toi » parce que le groupe nominal est ici au pluriel et que :

1. au pluriel l'article indéfini *un/une* devient *des*.
2. l'article indéfini *des* se réduit à *de/d'* devant un nom précédé d'un adjectif qualificatif<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Nombreuses références facilement accessibles pour ces deux règles, en voici une [sur le site du Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/articles)).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

La [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49118/17649) qui succède à celle-ci (avant la présente correction) justifie l'utilisation de « de » dans la locution « pas d'autre homme que », ce mot étant la forme  de l'article indéfini en contexte négatif de négation dite totale.   Les règles concernant ce point de grammaire peuventt être lue dans [La grammaire de l'étudiant finnophone (de Jean-Michel Kalmbach)](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49118/17649), la section particulière étant « Modifications dans une phrase négative ». L'essentiel est dit dans la réponse mentionnée et la présente correction à ma réponse, qu'annule la réponse mentionnée, est utilisé pour apporter quelques précisions.

> [Forme *de* devant CVD et sujet postposé](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/article-indefini.html#049) Quand l’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni (tou­tes les for­mes, c’est-à-dire singulier, pluriel et massif) dé­ter­mi­ne un grou­pe no­mi­nal qui est com­plé­ment de ver­be direct (CVD) d’un ver­be à la for­me né­ga­ti­ve, il prend gé­né­ra­le­ment la for­me **de** :
>
> ♦ J’ai une voiture. vs Je n’ai pas en­co­re **de** voiture.
> ♦ J’ai remar­qué des fautes. vs Je n’ai pas remar­qué **de** fautes.
> ♦ Nous n’avons pas appris **de** mots nouveaux.
> ♦ Aujourd’hui, je n’ai pas eu besoin de prendre **de** médicaments.
> ♦ Ne fais pas de bruit.

> [Exceptions](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/article-indefini.html#0501) Cepen­dant, cette règle de la transformation de l’ar­ti­cle dans une phra­se né­ga­ti­ve ne s’applique pas sys­té­ma­ti­que­ment. L’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni peut conserver sa for­me nor­ma­le dans les cas sui­vants.
> a)  Négation partielle
> b) La néga­tion porte sur un au­tre élé­ment que le CVD
> c) Affirma­tion cachée en né­ga­tion

> **a)** L’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni devant CVD d’une phra­se né­ga­ti­ve devient *de* quand la néga­tion est *totale*. Ex­em­ple : le lo­cu­teur devait acheter des pommes et ne l’a pas fait, il dit :
>
> - Je n’ai pas acheté **de** pommes.
>
> Donc il est revenu sans les pommes prévues, le com­plé­ment du ver­be est « nié » com­plè­tement (com­plé­ment = « zéro, rien »). De mê­me, dans la phra­se sui­vante, on dit que la police n’a rien trouvé qui puisse servir à accuser le suspect (com­plé­ment = « zéro, rien ») :
>
> - La police n’a pas pu trouver **de** preuves contre le suspect.
>
> Mais la néga­tion peut aus­si être **partielle** : le ver­be peut avoir un com­plé­ment, mais ce com­plé­ment est dif­fé­rent de celui prévu ou supposé. Dans ce cas, l’ar­ti­cle reste **gé­né­ra­le­ment** à la for­me nor­ma­le *des/du/de la/de*. Dans la phra­se sui­vante, la per­son­ne a bien acheté quel­que chose, mais ce ne sont pas des pommes. Ce qui est nié est la *nature* du com­plé­ment, et non pas le com­plé­ment tout entier :
>
> Je n’ai pas acheté **des** pommes, j’ai acheté des cerises.

C'est dans cette catégorie (a))  que convient l'exemple trouvé dans la réponse mentionnée ci-dessus.

- Je n'ai pas aimé **un** autre homme que toi, j'ai aimé une femme.

> **b)** La néga­tion peut aus­si être par­tielle en ce sens qu’elle ne porte pas sur le com­plé­ment direct du ver­be, mais sur un au­tre élé­ment de la phra­se, par ex­em­ple sur l’ad­jec­tif qui ca­ra­cté­ri­se le com­plé­ment (et non pas sur tout le com­plé­ment) :
>
> ■  Il ne faut pas y ac­cor­der une grande importance. [On peut y ac­cor­der de l’importance, mais pas trop.]
> ■ Il n’a pas obtenu des résultats vraiment intéressants [Il a bien obtenu des résultats, mais qui ne sont pas intéressants.]
> ■ La police n’a pas trouvé des preuves décisives contre le suspect. [La police a donc trouvé des preuves, mais elles n’étaient pas décisives.]
> ■ Nos voisins n’ont pas un petit voilier, ils ont un catamaran de 15 m !
>
> C’est éga­le­ment le cas quand la néga­tion porte sur un ad­ver­be ou un complément de phra­se. Ces élé­ments sont in­di­qués en italiques dans les exemples sui­vants :
>
> ■ Demain nous n’irons pas faire **du** ski.
> ■ Avec le temps qu’il a fait cet hiver, on n’a pas sou­vent fait **du** patinage sur le lac.
> ■ Autrefois, les gens ne mangeaient pas **de la** viande tous les jours.
> ■ Cette année, on n’est pas allés acheter **du** vin chez le producteur. [mais ailleurs]
> ■ Les chercheurs n’ont pas obtenu **des** résultats im­mé­dia­te­ment.
> ■ Adecco ne pourra pas vous proposer **des** missions avant votre arrivée en France.
> ■ Vous ne pourrez pas fabriquer **du** fromage avec des moyens au­si dérisoires.
> ■ La sépara­tion des déchets de verre est im­por­tan­te car on ne peut pas produire **du** verre incolore à partir d’un verre coloré.
> ■ Les Fran­çais ne boivent plus aus­si sou­vent **du** vin aux repas qu’il y a en­co­re vingt ans.

Voici un arrangement justifiant  l'usage de « un » selon les directives de cette section ( b)). Remarquer que la négation partielle ne porte pas sur une modification réelle du complément (adjectif ou autre), mais  sur la « modification zéro » (le manque de toute modification).

- — Alors tu as aimé un autre homme que moi ?
  — Non, je n'ai pas aimé **un** autre homme que toi, j'ai aimé un homme auquel je tenais plus que je n'ai jamais tenu à toi. [pas simplement un autre homme]

> **c)** L’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni conserve aus­si sa for­me nor­ma­le si la néga­tion cache une affirma­tion déguisée ou at­té­nuée, no­tam­ment dans les questions polies ou dans l’in­ter­ro­ga­tion indi­rec­te :
>
> ■  Vous n’auriez pas **de** la monnaie ?
> ■ Tu ne pourrais pas me prêter **un** sac de cou­chage pour les vacances ?
> ■ Une associa­tion locale me demande si je ne pourrais pas leur fournir **des** tee-shirts avec leur logo.
> ■ On peut se demander si cette déclara­tion n’a pas donné **des** idées à des apprentis terroristes, à moins que ce ne soit les films d’Hollywood.
> […]
> Dans tou­tes ces phra­ses, le ver­be cor­res­pond en fait à un ver­be affirmatif (si je pou­vais leur fournir / a sans doute donné des idées […]).

L'arrangement suivant est une illustration pour la présente section, mais certains changements supplémentaires sont nécéssaires.

- Tu n'aimerais pas **un** autre homme que moi par hazard ?

Ceci dit, il convient de préciser que les utilisateurs du langage, même les écrivains, ne sont pas parfaitement conscients de toutes les subtilités qui viennent d'être exposées, et donc qu'il faut faire des vérifications dans les grammaires jusqu'à ce qu'on soit sûr de ce qui est écrit (ou dit), à moins d'être partisan d'un certain laisser-faire.

([réf. 2019](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Ab%C3%A9lard/kkzADwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22pas+un+autre+homme+que%22&pg=PT30&printsec=frontcover)) La socratité ne donne pas un autre homme que Socrate. Mais l'idée de Socrate ne contient pas toujours tout ce que désigne ce nom

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_Europe_et_les_anges/GW6VtG1ejgcC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22pas+un+autre+homme+que%22&pg=PA175&printsec=frontcover)) Ils finiront par comprendre que je n'épouserai pas un autre homme que toi. Je ne veux pas me fâcher avec la famille de mon père, mais il faut qu'ils comprennent :

([réf., 2017](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_seigneur_de_Trouville/BZY6DwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22pas+un+autre+homme+que%22&pg=PT158&printsec=frontcover)) Je ne chercherai pas un autre homme que vous parce que je ne me remarierai jamais. Croyez-moi quand je vous dis que le mariage n'est pas pour moi, Henri.

Comment: Il n'est pas question d'une quelconque  tournure littéraire dans la question actuelle qui n'a rien à voir avec la question initiale (voir l'historique des edits).

Comment: @None Qui parle d'une tournure littéraire ? Je précise que ce n'est pas rune tournure **qui n'est pas** resteinte à la langue littéraire et qu'on peut l'employer dans la conversation courante.

Comment: cf. Toi: "Note Pour répondre à un commentaire dans le post initial, non, cette tournure n'est pas littéraire, c'est de la langue courante." On  ne peut que comprendre "cette tournure dont je viens de parler". Je te faisais remarquer que personne ne demande si elle est littéraire, relis donc la question. Et le  commentaire dont tu parles ne porte pas sur la tournure dont tu parles.

Comment: @None Non, je parle du second commentaire sous le post initial, celui de user ovide.

Comment: Mais je l'avais compris et je faisais remarquer que ce commentaire que tu mentionnes ne concerne pas la question à laquelle tu réponds, puisque la question a été modifiée après éclaircissement de la confusion initiale chez le PO.

Comment: De nombreux éléments de ta question m'échappent. Pour expliquer tes mots "La forme négative n'a pas d'incidence" pourrais-tu s'il te plait mettre à la forme affirmative les phrases de ta réponse *Je n'ai pas connu d'autre homme que toi* et les 2 phrases qui suivent en utilisant *de*. 
 Je ne parle pas de la première parce que dans « personne d'autre » (comme dans « quelqu'un d'autre ») c'est « personne » et « quelqu'un » qui entraine la présence de *de* qui n'est plus alors article (comme dans *... aime d'autre que toi*) mais préposition.

Comment: Tu dis "le nombre peut être pluriel" forcément au pluriel un/une devient *des/de* devant un adjectif, donc quel est le rapport ? Je ne vois pas comment tu fais le lien.
 Dans la phrase « il en trouvera d'autres » (dont le singulier pour moi est « il en trouvera un autre »)  c'est l'article indéfini pluriel « des » qui est réduit à **de** devant l'adjectif **autres** au pluriel.

Comment: @none Il y a dans ma réponse une erreur grossière dès le départ, et il vaut mieux que je la supprime.

Comment: @ovide Désolé de vous avoir fait peiner pour rien tout le long de  cette réponse ; elle contient une erreur absurde et il ne faut pas en tenir compte. Je vais la supprimer pour l'instant. Il est possible que je puisse la corriger plus tard.